# ssh2: Unable to initialize module

Tags: ssh, centos, php, libssh2

I install ssh2 on my server
but when i check the result is :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20100525
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
>   These options need to match in Unknown on line 0

I uses centos 6 and directadmin

Comment: The error message means that you did install the wrong version of the SSH2 extension. You need to remove it again and install a version that matches with your PHP version. If you need further guidance, you need to show which PHP package you use extactly. See the the documentation of your package manager (most likely `yum`) to find out how you can find out which PHP package you've got installed and which SSH2 PHP extension package you've got installed. Add the information (both the command to find out as well as the output) to your question by editing it.

Comment: can you show the steps you have done? if you try the way described here: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php#109853 .. does it work?

Comment: do you have root ssh access to the box?

Comment: Hi all thanks for answer,
I ever try that link but still same.
Yes, I've root access. I try this too :
http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=30682&p=242694#post242694 and
http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=44633
etc.
the result still same.
 
my php version is 5.3.27 and I've try ssh2-12.0 and ssh2-11.30 . the result is same.
when I try ssh2-11.0 the result is make *** [error] cannot make ssh2.so
I try rebuild php from custombuild directadmin and install shh2 again but error still same.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

libssh2 is notoriously difficult to install. Personally, I would recommend you try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html).

Comment: A nightmare to install, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install ssh2 through yum, enabling [remi.repo](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2018/12/10/Install-PHP-7.3-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora) if required:

`$ sudo yum install php-pecl-ssh2`

It will install `php-pecl-ssh2` package of the same version as your PHP is.

But it also possible to install it through pecl if you have any reasons to do it:

1. `# yum install php-devel`
2. `# pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`
3. `# pecl install ssh2`

Tested for Oracle Linux 7.

Comment: There is no need to "build" (pecl command) from sources, when binary packages exist in the same repo than php.